# change charters in a string based on vcf table data

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fasta, genome, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a long string file (`string.txt`) (`abcdefghijklmnop`)
and a vcf table (`file.vcf`) which lools like that

```
position 2 4 6 10 n...
name1 a b c d
name2 x y z a
namen...
```

the table also contain `"mis"` and `"het"` and in this case the character should not be replaced

I want to change the characters in the specific location and store all the strings in a new file that will look like this

```
>name1
aacbecghidklmnop
>name2
axcyezghiaklmnop
```

is there a way to do it in a bash loop ?

Comment: It's not clear what are you replacing with what? where did "aacbec" and "axcyez" come from?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. the string i want to manipulate is in the file string.txt. based on the data in the vcf table i want to create new strings with the modification in the specific locations listed in the vcf table. hope it is clearer now

Comment: No, still not clear.  Where is the spec that generates these modified strings?

Comment: oh sorry, just saw it was edited. i've fixed the table in the question

Comment: You should probably provide specific example, as toy example you provide is somewhat confusing. Also, this will be tough to do strictly in `bash`. Do you mean using Linux commands like `awk`, `tr`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
mapfile -t string < <(fold -w1 "string.txt")
# set string to an array of single characters: ("a" "b" "c" "d" ..)

while read -ra ary; do
    if [[ ${ary[0]} = "position" ]]; then
        # 1st line of file.vcf
        declare -a pos=("${ary[@]:1}")
        # now the array pos holds: (2 4 6 10 ..)
    else
        # 2nd line of file.vcf and after
        declare -a new=("${string[@]}")
        # make a copy of string to modify
        for ((i=0; i<${#pos[@]}; i++ )); do
            repl="${ary[$i+1]}"    # replacement
            if [[ $repl != "mis" && $repl != "het" ]]; then
                new[${pos[$i]}-1]="$repl"
                # modify the position with the replacement
            fi
        done
        echo ">${ary[0]}"
        (IFS=""; echo "${new[*]}")
        # print the modified array as a concatenated string
    fi
done < "file.vcf"
```

string.txt:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

file.vcf:

```
position 2 4 6 10
name1 a b c d
name2 x y z a
name3 i mis k l
```

Output:

```
>name1
aacbecghidklmnop
>name2
axcyezghiaklmnop
>name3
aicdekghilklmnop
```

I have tried to embed explanations as comments in the script above, but
if you still have a question, please feel free to ask.

Hope this helps.